# Quarkus: connect to cloudsql db (gcp) with native image

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

I've set up a prod configuration for my datasource to connect to a GCP MySQL instance, basically following this tutorial: https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-google-cloud#using-cloud-sql

Configuration is:

```
%prod.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other
%prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql:///dbname
%prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
%prod.quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
%prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.cloudSqlInstance=my:gcloudconnection:string
%prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

Also I added it to maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-jib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then I build my container with

```
./mvnw package -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dmaven.test.skip
```

Then I push the image to my GCP registry and start it from GoogleRun.

This part works fine!

The point is, I want a native image to be used, so I add `-Pnative` to the maven command.

From there, the first problem is that the MySQL factory lib isn't imported by graal because there is no explicit reference to it. So I have to register manually within quarkus:

```
@RegisterForReflection(targets = arrayOf(com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory::class))
class MyReflectionConfiguration {}
```

Now the error is

```
2021-11-10 11:14:08.027 HNEC
2021-11-10 10:14:08,025 WARN [org.hib.eng.jdb.env.int.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread: <default>) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
2021-11-10 11:14:08.027 HNEC
at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-11-10 11:14:08.027 HNEC
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore(GoogleUtils.java:86)
```

So it refers to google-http-client not being compatible with a native image. The line itself in the lib is

```
      InputStream keyStoreStream = GoogleUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("google.p12");
```

(so it means that GoogleUtils class is included in the native image, but not the `google.p12` file).

I could import this file explicitly in my app (I tried to ;-) with no success) but I am sure there is a better way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `resources-config.json` in your application resources to include the .p12 file.

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "pattern": ".*\\.p12$"
    }
  ]
}
```

And add the below configuration in your `application.properties`

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args =-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json
```

[Here](https://quarkus.native.additional-build-args%20=-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json) is the official documentation for the same.